# Sonarqube server java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)

Tags: sonarqube, heap-memory, amazon-linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHyC3.png)i am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)  error on Sonarqube server.
and my analysis is successful in Jenkins but reports are not being published on sonarserver.
it is giving this error. 
attaching screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHyC3.png)
 Kindly help

Comment: The error message is quite to the point. Increase the Java heap size?

Comment: I have increased by sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError still it is giving same error

Comment: I don't know how large your builds are, but 1024m is really not very much. For reference our build server uses 16348m. Try to double and then triple the figure if you have the memory.